# AppDelegate.m : Build input file cannot be found for IOS build/run-ios

Tags: react-native

After unsuccessful installing MS code push module on React Native 0.68.0 app/Monterey 12.4/Xcode 13 , `react-native run-ios` starts to throw error:

```
Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app6/ios/xyz_app6/AppDelegate.m'
```

Here is the AppDelegate.m:

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

The same error above appears in Xcode build as well. It seems to be a common issue with IOS but solutions online seems not working in my app. There is `AppDelegate.m` for project under Xcode and was unchanged (change was removed). What is missing here?

Comment: The version of Xcode? Also, make sure to run `pod deintegrate` & `pod install`

Answer (score 2):

Change all `AppDelegate.m` into `AppDelegate.mm` inside `project.pbxproj` (a file with temptation not to look into).